’m having trouble resolving some dependencies in my Android project using Gradle
AILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileStageDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:stageDebugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find com.saurabharora.customtabs:customtabs:1.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.bottlerocketstudios:vault:1.4.2.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.xwray:groupie:2.5.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.5.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.5.1.
Required by:
project :app


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 32s
Checked build.gradle files to ensure google() and mavenCentral() repositories are included.
Added additional repositories like JitPack if needed.
tried different versions of the dependency to see if the issue was with a specific version.
Added repositories like JitPack or specific Maven URLs if the library is known to be hosted there.
Verified that the dependency coordinates (group ID, artifact ID, version) were correct and free of typos.
What I Was Expecting:
I expected Gradle to be able to locate and download the specified dependencies successfully from the configured repositories.
I expected that adding or correcting repositories would resolve any issues related to missing dependencies.
I hoped that trying a different version of the library would solve the issue if the specified version was not available.
I aimed to resolve the build errors and get a successful Gradle build with all dependencies correctly resolved.

Those are hosted on bintray which is now shutdown. I checked only some random plugin you have like com.bottlerocketstudios:vault:1.4.2 you can see that here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bottlerocketstudios/vault/1.4.2 it is hosted in jcenter bintray

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The libraries mentioned in the logs, belong to jcenter repository. And since jcenter is shut down, the project isn't able to download the required dependencies.
You must look out for alternatives to these libraries that are present in mavenCentral
